# Is there a way to find the event history on Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I defined a schedule event in Cloudwatch to trigger a lambda. Is there a way for me to find the event payload received in lambda? I know I can print the event and context in lambda but I am looking for a solution to find it without changing lambda source code. Because I don't have permission to update lambda. 
Whether Cloudwatch provide a history event viewer I can use to check it?

Comment: If you are just doing a scheduled event, then you are also specifying the payload. Is there a reason you need to log what you are already defining?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in **AWS CloudTrail**. It records all API calls to your account.

In this situation, it is actually CloudWatch Events calling the AWS Lambda function, but I *think* it should still create a record in CloudTrail. (Let us know what you find!)

Comment: Cloudtrail is not enabled on my AWS account. When I check cloudtrail for lambda, it only has updateFunction, createFunction events. And there is only ALARM event for cloudwatch I can find in cloudtrail.

Answer (score 0):

As John said, CloudTrail is the best option. You actually have to enable CloudTrail specifically for Lambda, so make sure you tick that option. I am uncertain how best to locate the payload though. I'd suggest you search using both the ARN of the CloudWatch Event Rule and the ARN of the Lambda function. One or the other should record the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have CloudWatch send the message to an Amazon SNS topic.

Then, subscribe the Lambda function to the topic so that it receives the message it was originally getting. (Make sure you use 'Raw Message' delivery.)

You can then also subscribe to the SNS topic to receive a copy of the message sent by the CloudWatch schedule.